# Is there a computationally efficient way of check if there exists difference(s) between two nested arrays?

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, performance, time

I have two 2D arrays of ints and are the same length, but they are *very* large. I want to find if there exists at least one difference between the two arrays.

Note: I don't need to find out what the differences are, I just need to return `true` if there is at least one difference else `false`.

Right now I'm using two for loops to iterate through the indices and check if `arr1[i][j] !== arr2[i][j]`, but this is taking over 60 seconds worst case due to size.

Is there a better way to make this comparison?

Comment: I'm not sure it's faster but have you tried to use `JSON.stringify` and compare the strings?

Comment: The compiler probably is clever enough to do this for you, but if it is not then you can get a win by `let row1 = arr1[i]; let row2 = arr2[i]` out of the inner loop then in the inner loop check `row1[j] !== row2[j]`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you maintain the data structures in question (nested arrays), you can't get any faster than this, you have to check every element in general.

A few particular optimizations that you may conditionally apply however:

1. I'm fairly certain that flat arrays are faster to index, and you can use `i * width + j` to maintain your accesors similar, though obviously not identical.
2. If one of the arrays doesn't change often, and is so a reference you're checking against, you'll likely get very good results by hashing. You store the hash of your reference array every time you change it (again, it has to not be often), and every time you need to run your check against a new array you can hash he tested array and check it against the other calculated hash. Note that this can give false positives, so if the hashes match you need to actually check every element to make sure it actually is an equality.

And note that the above aren't either-or, implementing both will give you very good results!